Problems with CodeIgniter Shield and customised users table
I am using the latest version of CodeIgniter shield.
I have customised my users table to add some new fields, I have also customised my registration form. I have added new fields for first_name, last_name, job_title
I followed the guidance at https://shield.codeigniter.com/customization/adding_attributes_to_users/
When a user now tries to register and error message is thrown [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbname.dbo.users'
My users table is called auth_users which I think is what is causing the problem. I have altered the name of the table through the supported route App\Config\Auth.php
User registration has worked before I attempted to add the additional fields.
Also creating the migration file worked no problem and the new fields were added to the db table correctly.
